# Bundle has content that does NOT have a .pom file

Tags: pom.xml

I'm trying to deploy my library via maven central. But while deploying the jar file, I got this error "Bundle has content that does NOT have a .pom file". But my project had pom.xml normally. What's the problem?

The link below is my library that I want to publish on maven central. This is my first post, so I made it for testing purposes.

https://github.com/NiceTiming/TestLib

To resolve this error, I recreated the project and re-configured the pom.xml settings, but the error was the same.